# ubuntu18.04でcanon satera lbp6240のドライバーをインストールする方法

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Let's note sz6にubuntuをインストールして使っています。
プリンターを使うためにubuntuにドライバーをインストールする必要があるのですが、https://cweb.canon.jp/cgi-bin/download/select-os.cgi?i_cd_pr_catg=002&i_cd_pr=3649&i_pr_search_word=&i_fl_select_pr_catg=1
このリンクからlinuxを選び、ダウンロードし、debianを選んでインストールしてもドライバーがインストールされません。だいぶ調べてみたのですが該当する記事やサイトが見つからず質問します。

Comment: このサイトでは問題ないようですね。https://bonno.idi-s.com/?p=9581　試されましたか？

Comment: ファイルは https://cweb.canon.jp/drv-upd/lasershot/linux/carps2linux.html の「ダウンロード開始」をクリックしてダウンロードされるファイル(linux-carps2lbp-drv-v500-jp-17.tar.gz)でしょうか？

Comment: metropolisさん、ありがとうございます。そうです、ダウンロード開始をクリックしてダウンロードされるファイルです

Comment: 有線LANでの接続方法でしたので試しておりません

Comment: Canon LBP6240

これはさらに簡単。Canonからドライバー出てますからね。ドライバーダウンロードして（この場合はcaprs2ドライバー）

$ sudo ./install.sh

以上w なんていい時代だっ！ と書いてありますので、wifi、有線LANは関係会と思います。

Comment: 「インストールされない」とは具体的にどのような状態ですか？「インストーラが途中でエラーになる」「一見インストーラは正常終了するが、プリンタが動作しない」などいくつかのケースが考えられます。

Comment: 池田茂樹さん、ありがとうございます。コマンドは打ってみましたがコマンドが見つかりませんと出ます。なにか少し変えたら出来るのだと思いますが、何せLinuxの知識が乏しいもので..すみません。cubickさん、インストールされないというのは｢一見インストーラは正常終了するが、プリンタが動作しない｣といったものです。アプリケーションのアイコンは出るのですが、クリックしても起動しません。